# In general relativity, are light-like curves light-like geodesics?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

Just as the title. If a curve is light-like, i.e. a null-curve, is it definitely a null geodesic?

Answer (score 23):

No.

Here is a simple counterexample due to my friend Antonio Russo, a fellow UCLA grad student. Set $c=1$ for convenience, and consider the following curve in $\mathbb R^{2,1}$ (aka three-dimensional flat space with one time dimension $t$ and two space dimensions $x$ and $y$):
\begin{align}
  t(\lambda) = \lambda, \qquad x(\lambda) = R\cos(\alpha\lambda), \qquad y(\lambda) = R\sin(\alpha\lambda).
\end{align}
This is the trajectory of particle moving along a circle.  Notice that
\begin{align}
  \dot x^\mu \dot x_\mu = -1+(R\alpha)^2,
\end{align}
where the overdot denotes derivative with respect to $\lambda$, and we are using $(-,+,+)$ signature.  Therefore this curve is null if we choose $R\alpha = 1$.  It is not a geodesic, however, since geodesics in flat space are straight lines, and it is not a straight line.

Comment: I believe it should be $y(\lambda) = R\sin(\alpha\lambda)$.

Comment: Geodesics are a concept from General Relativity and can be curves, not straight lines,no?

Comment: @annav Notice that I wrote "Consider the following curve in $\mathbb R^{2,1}$," which is three-dimensional Minkowski space (flat space).  The geodesics in flat space are straight, so this is an example where the set of geodesics in a certain geometry does not coincide with the set of null curves.  Of course you can, however, come up with similar examples for non-trivially curved spacetimes as well, but I think that overcomplicates the issue.

Comment: This example is simple enough and illustrates the problem clearly, and I have got the idea. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear Anna, geodesics are "curves" because in a general curved spacetime, it isn't even possible to find something that could be called "straight lines". On the other hand, geodesics are closest to this goal because geodesics are, by the definition translated in a way, the "straightest" lines you can find in a general space! So at short distances, when any space becomes nearly flat, geodesics must be straight lines, too. In a curved spacetime, geodesics is whatever you get by connecting these straight infinitesimal pieces i.e. by parallel transport of the forward line segment.

Comment: @dj_mummy Thanks.  I hesitate to include the null geodesic equation, because then I would feel compelled to write more explanations, and I kind of like the fact that the answer is just a short, sweet, and simple counterexample: "Everything should be made as simple as possible but no simpler" -Einstein

Comment: joshphysics: "_consider the following curve_ $$\begin{align} t(\lambda)=\lambda, \qquad x(\lambda)=R\cos(\alpha\lambda), \qquad y(\lambda)=R\sin(\alpha\lambda). \end{align}$$ -- Along with that let's also consider curve $$\begin{align} t(\lambda)=\lambda, \qquad x(\lambda)=R\cos(-\alpha\lambda), \qquad y(\lambda) = R\sin(-\alpha\lambda). \end{align}$$ Does either or both of these curves correspond to "the propagation trajectory" of a light signal (e.g. a photon)? If so, should the given region, with its parametrization "$\mathbb R^{2,1}$" be called "_three-dimensional flat space with [...]_"?

Comment: joshphysics: "_consider the following curve_ $$\begin{align} t(\lambda)=\lambda,\qquad x(\lambda)=R\cos(\alpha\lambda),\qquad y(\lambda)=R\sin(\alpha\lambda). \end{align}$$ Let's refer to it as$$\gamma : \mathbb R\rightarrow\cal M.$$ Now, for any two different real numbers $a$ and $b$ is$$ s[ \gamma[ a ], \gamma[ b ] ] = 0~?,$$ where $s$ is (a suitable generalization of) a [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space), as induced by the signals exchanged between events which are elements of the region $\cal M$ under consideration. If not, should $\gamma$ really be called "_null curve_"?

Comment: @user12262 A curve is null provided its tangent is everywhere null, so yes, $\gamma$ is null provided $R\alpha = 1$.

Comment: joshphysics: "_A curve is null provided its tangent is everywhere null, so yes $\gamma$ is null_" -- Hmm ... "_provided_ $R \alpha=1$." -- Sure (I had neglected to specify that above); that's what I meant by curve $\gamma$. Alright, so $\gamma$ is "everywhere null". But ... you do agree, don't you, that for any two distinct real numbers $a$ and $b$ (i.e. from the domain of $\gamma$) there is (at least) one other curve $$\theta : [a,~b] \rightarrow \cal M$$ such that $$\theta[~a~] = \gamma[~a~],\qquad \theta[~b~] = \gamma[~b~],$$ but curve $\theta$ is "everywhere positive", right? [contd.]

Comment: @user12262 What do you mean by "everywhere positive"?

Comment: So, I wonder how to call a curve (if there are any) which is "everywhere null" (as is $\gamma$ in the example), and which moreover has the property that **it doesn't have** any such "everywhere positive [chord curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28geometry%29)" (as $\theta$ in the example) at all. (Nor any "everywhere negative chord curve" between any two "points" of the very special null curve under consideration; as far as such "negative curves" might exist at all.) How would you/we call such a "very special null curve"? (I plan to ask that question formally, too.)

Comment: @user12262 I think this chat is getting somewhat off-topic.  I suggest waiting for answers to your formal question.

Comment: I've submitted the question ["_Are there more distinctive names of “null curves” with certain additional properties (absence of “chord curves”)?_", PSE/q/127718](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127718/are-there-more-distinctive-names-of-null-curves-with-certain-additional-proper) as a "formal" follow-up question. The purpose is foremost to establish some relation between terminology which is based on presuming manifolds, coordinates, and somesuch, and terminology describing observational content, such as signal fronts (light).

Answer (score 6):

In 3 or more spacetime dimensions the answer is *No,* as simple counterexamples show already in Minkowski space. However, in 2 spacetime dimensions, it actually holds, cf. the next theorem.

> *Theorem:* In an arbitrary 1+1D [Lorentzian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) $M$, a smooth light-like curve satisfies the geodesic equation.

*Proof:* Let there be given a parametrized null curve $\gamma: [a,b] \to M$ with zero parameter speed squared

$$\tag{A} g(\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma})~=~0,\qquad \dot{\gamma} ~\neq~0. $$

Here dot denotes differentiation wrt. to the parameter $\lambda$. By further differentiation of eq. (A) wrt. $\lambda$, we get that $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}$ and $\dot{\gamma}$ are orthogonal/perpendicular

$$\tag{B} g(\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma})~=~0 $$

wrt. to the Lorentzian metric $g$. Here $\nabla$ is the [Levi-Civita (LC) connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection). In eq. (B) we have used the metric property of the LC. connection.

Next recall that in 1+1D, the [light-cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone)

$$\tag{C} \mathbb{R}n_+ \cup \mathbb{R}n_- ~\subset~ T_pM$$

in a point $p\in M$ consists of two null rays, spanned by two non-zero null vectors $n_{\pm}\neq 0$, with the inner products

$$\tag{D} g_p(n_{\pm},n_{\pm})~=~0, \qquad g_p(n_{\pm},n_{\mp})~\neq~0. $$

The pair $n_{\pm}$ also happens to be a basis for the tangent space $T_pM$.
In other words, in the point $p\in M$, the vector $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}$ must be a linear combination of $n_{\pm}$. Moreover the null vector $\dot{\gamma}$ must be proportional to either $n_+$ or $n_-$. Together with eq. (B), it follows that $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}$ and $\dot{\gamma}$ are collinear/parallel/proportional

$$\tag{E} \nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma} ~\parallel~  \dot{\gamma}~\neq~0. $$

In other words, there exists a function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\tag{F} \nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}~=~f \dot{\gamma}.$$

Eq. (F) is the eq. for a [non-affinely parametrized geodesic](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=non+affinely+parameterized+geodesic). Locally one may reparametrized a non-affinely parametrized geodesic into 
an affinely parametrized [geodesic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic). An affinely parametrized geodesic $\gamma: [a,b] \to M$ satisfies by definition $$\tag{G} \nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}~=~0.$$ 
$\Box$

Answer (score -3):

No. In a Euclidean space, you can have all sort of curves. Not all of them are geodesics. This is also true in Minkowski space.