# Are there more distinctive names of "null curves" with certain additional properties (absence of "chord curves")?

Tags: general-relativity, terminology

In [this answer (to the question "*In general relativity, are light-like curves light-like geodesics?*", PSE/q/76170)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/76173) a particular example of a curve is discussed whose "*tangent is everywhere null*" and which is therefore called a "*null curve*". I'll restate the example curve explicitly as

$$\nu : \mathbb R \rightarrow \cal M,$$

together with a coordinate function

$$\mathbf r : \cal M \rightarrow \mathbb R^{1,2}; \qquad \mathbf r := \{~t,~x,~y~\}$$

such that

$$\mathbf r \circ \nu[~\lambda~] := \{~t_{\nu}[~\lambda~],~x_{\nu}[~\lambda~],~y_{\nu}[~\lambda~]~\} = \{~\lambda,~\text{Cos}[~\lambda~],~\text{Sin}[~\lambda~]~\}.$$

The calculation of the corresponding "*tangent*" value proceeds (roughly) via

$$\begin{align}
\left( \frac{d}{d\lambda}[~t_{\nu}[~\lambda~]~] \right)^2 - \left( \frac{d}{d\lambda}[~x_{\nu}[~\lambda~]~] \right)^2 - \left( \frac{d}{d\lambda}[~y_{\nu}[~\lambda~]~] \right)^2 & = & \\
1 - \left( -\text{Sin}[~\lambda~] \right)^2 - \left( \text{Cos}[~\lambda~] \right)^2 & = 0\end{align}$$
for all values $\lambda$ in the domain of "*null curve*" $\nu$.

Now, interestingly, for any two distinct values $\lambda := a$ and $\lambda := b$ from the domain of "null curve" $\nu$, there exist curves (which in the following are suggestively called "[chord curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28geometry%29)")
$$\kappa_{ab} : [~a, ~b~] \subset \mathbb R \rightarrow \cal M,$$
such that
$$\kappa_{ab}[~a~] = \nu[~a~], \qquad \kappa_{ab}[~b~] = \nu[~b~]$$
and: the "*tangent* of $\kappa_{ab}$" is everywhere **positive**.

As one concrete case consider
$$\mathbf r \circ \kappa[~\lambda~] := \{~t_{\kappa}[~\lambda~],~x_{\kappa}[~\lambda~],~y_{\kappa}[~\lambda~]~\} = $$ $$\{~\small{\lambda,~\text{Cos}[~a~] + \left( \frac{\lambda - a}{b - a} \right) \left( \text{Cos}[~b~] - \text{Cos}[~a~] \right),~\text{Sin}[~a~] + \left( \frac{\lambda - a}{b - a} \right) \left( \text{Sin}[~b~] - \text{Sin}[~a~] \right)~}\},$$

with the corresponding "*tangent*" value

$$\left( \frac{d}{d\lambda}[~t_{\kappa}[~\lambda~]~] \right)^2 - \left( \frac{d}{d\lambda}[~x_{\kappa}[~\lambda~]~] \right)^2 - \left( \frac{d}{d\lambda}[~y_{\kappa}[~\lambda~]~] \right)^2 = $$ $$\small{1 - \left( \frac{\text{Cos}[~b~] - \text{Cos}[~a~]}{b - a} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{\text{Sin}[~b~] - \text{Sin}[~a~]}{b - a} \right)^2 = 1 - 4 \left( \frac{\text{Sin}[~(b - a)/2~]}{b - a} \right)^2 \gt 0.}$$

(As a sidenote: similarly, for given distinct values $\lambda := a$ and $\lambda := b$ from the domain of "null curve" $\nu$, one may ask for "chord curves" whose "*tangent*" value should be everywhere **negative**; but I have not been able to construct a corresponding concrete example. In the following, it is not necessary to distinguish "positive chord curves" from "negative" ones, if cases of the latter exist at all. Relevant is only that the "*tangent*" value of a "chord curve" exists everywhere and is **not "null" anywhere**.)

**My question is:**
Is there some specific name (i.e. more distinctive than "just another *null curve*") referring to "*null curves*" which do **not have any** "chord curves" at all? (Are such special cases of "*null curves*" perhaps called "*null geodesics*"?)

Comment: Ī once participated in a related discussion on one forum, now at [this link](http://www.physicsforums.com/threads/null-geodesic-definition-by-extremisation.768196/). Maybe you will extract something useful from it.

Answer (score 1):

As in your post, let $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ be a smooth curve onto a Lorentzian manifold.

You might be interested in [this math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502752/spacelike-curves-definitions) post, indicating that all points in more than two Lorentzian dimensions can be joined by a spacelike curve, so space-like chord curves are utterly uninteresting, as they can be constructed from taking a small tube around $\gamma$ from $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma(b)$ and letting the spacelike path wind around that tube.

The existence of time-like chord curves implies that $\gamma$ is not a maximum of the length functional, and that therefore $\gamma$ is not a length-maximizing geodesic. I am not yet sure if it implies that $\gamma$ is no geodesic at all, since geodesics on Lorentzian manifolds are weird. However, if time-like chord curves exist between every $\gamma(t)$ and $\gamma'(t)$ for every $t,t'\in [a,b]$, then $\gamma$ is no geodesic, since Lorentzian time-like geodesics are locally length-maximizing.

Thus, being a null geodesic indeed implies that, locally, there are no time-like chord curves.

Comment: ACuriousMind: "_You might be interested in this math.SE [MSE/q/502752] post, indicating that all points in more than two Lorentzian dimensions can be joined by a spacelike curve [...] constructed from taking a small tube around $\gamma$ [...] and letting the spacelike path wind around that tube._" -- Ah, of course! (+1. That's explained so well, I put off looking at [MSE/q/502752](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/502752) for now ;) I'd even give +3 for your kind use of that "seat-of-my-pants" terminology "chord curve". (Did I indeed guess the 'technical term'? Hawing-Ellis is expensive! ...)

Comment: ACuriousMind: "_space-like chord curves are uninteresting [...] Thus, being a null geodesic indeed implies that, locally, there are no time-like chord curves._" -- `1:`Conversely, my question still is: Is there a null curve without **any** time-like chord curves (whether "_local_", or otherwise) **not** called a "_null geodesic_"? (Also, I wonder how the term "_light-like curve_" relates to either of these ...) `2:`Could you please make explicit (and surely you've got the means to try) how to determine for a null curve with (at least) one time-like chord curve whether that's "_local_", or not?

Comment: @user12262: For $2.$, I am afraid I, at least, cannot. We only know that *there are neighbourhoods* for every point on $\mathcal{M}$ on which the geodesics are length-maximizing (that's what locally means), not how big they are (for a sphere (admittedly Riemannian), the maximal neighborhood would be the hemispheres, but I've no idea how to proceed for general manifolds). For, $1.$ ("light-like" and "null" are synonymous) but I am again unable (at least for now) to find either a rigorous argument showing that time-like chords imply no geodesics or construct a counterexample.

Comment: ACuriousMind: "_For `1.`"light-like" and "null" are synonymous_" -- Really!? ... I looked up what I suppose(d) to be the source of all that "_-likeness_" terminology: [H. Minkowski, "_Raum und Zeit_", (1909)](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Space_and_Time). There appears (in translation) "_space-like_", and "_time-like_", but, curiously, **no mentioning of** "_light-like_". Instead: of certain **"_cones_"** having to do with "_sending light_" or "_receiving light_"; i.e. surely what's called "[_light cone_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone)". So I'll try to be more careful ...

Comment: @user12262: The old masters are not always the place to go - their terminology is often quite different from what we use today, and often, their approaches are a weird mix between "intuition" and rigorous computation. In the field of "Lorentzian geometry" as we know it today, we call (for a metric with signature $(-+++)$), vectors $v$ with $g(v,v) < 0$ *time-like*, $g(v,v) = 0$ *light-like* (more physical) or *null* (more mathy) and $g(v,v) > 0$ *space-like*. The terminology extends then to curves if the tangent vector of the curves is in one of these three classes at every point of the curve.

Comment: ACuriousMind: "_In [...] "Lorentzian geometry" as we know it today [...]_" -- Honestly, that's at best secondary to me. First: How, from given observational data (e.g. having "stated/sent signals", "detected/received signals"), to derive unambiguous real number values (such as "Null", or "$\pi$", etc.) The masterplan: "_[All our well-substantiated space-time propositions amount to the determination of space-time coincidences {such as} encounters between two or more recognizable material points](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Foundation_of_the_Generalised_Theory_of_Relativity#ch.3.p.776)._"

Comment: ACuriousMind: Since I only now appreciate "_light cones_" **in distinction to** the notions ("_of "Lorentzian geometry" as we know it today_") that you described (ever so thoroughly and patiently), and considering that my OP question was foremost placed as a follow-up to ["_In general relativity, are light-like curves light-like geodesics?_", PSE/q/76170](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76170), I should go on to ask (roughly): "Given a set of events such that any one of them is 'on the light cones' of all remaining others, do **all pairs** of them constitute 'null intervals'?".

Comment: @user12262: You would have to define "null interval" different from *"There is a null geodesic joining the two points"* to not make that a tautology. Digging through some works, it seems not many bother to define the notion of "space-time interval" at all away from flat Minkowski space on general Lorentzian manifolds. In Minkowski space, it is certainly true that points that lie on each others light cones constitute null intervals.

Comment: ACuriousMind: "_You would have to define "null interval" different from "There is a null geodesic joining the two points" to not make that a tautology._" -- Certainly. How do you like [_"Given two events such that either one of them is 'on the light cone' of the other, do they constitute a 'null interval'?"_, PSE/q/127859](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127859) ? "_In Minkowski space, it is certainly true_" -- I bet. But where's the rub e.g. with "closed time-like curves" or similar ... errm ... aspects of "_the field of "Lorentzian geometry" as we know it today_"? ...