# Given two events such that either one of them is 'on the light cone' of the other, do they constitute a 'null interval'?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-space

One basic part of determining a  [metric (or applicable generalization)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Generalized_metrics) of a given set $\cal S$ of events (up to an arbitrary non-zero constant) is to determine to which pairs among those events, $\mathscr P, \mathscr Q \in \cal S$, to assign the (suitably generalized) distance value $s[ \mathscr P, \mathscr Q  ] = s[ \mathscr Q, \mathscr P  ] = 0$.

In general relativity, is this assignment for two such events $\mathscr P$ and $\mathscr Q$ made if and only if event $\mathscr Q$ is 'on the light cone of' event $\mathscr P$, and vice versa event $\mathscr P$ is 'on the light cone of' event $\mathscr Q$;
i.e. in the (physics related) terminology of H. Minkowski, "*Raum und Zeit*", (1909):
if and only if 
["*one event had sent light towards the other, or had received light from the other*"](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Space_and_Time) ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is quite right. A 'null' separation between two events is also called 'lightlike' since it implies that the points are on each other's light cone (the property is symmetric; it is in fact an equivalence relation now that I think about it)

Comment: Danu: Thanks (+1) for the emphatically unambiguous answer. (To me, that's some relief after having had a brush with some intricacies of ["_the field of "Lorentzian geometry" as we know it today_", PSE/a/127734](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/127734) ...) Now: what might be the next more complicated but still answerable question? ...))