# Example of lightlike curve that's not a geodesic in Lorentz spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, spacetime, metric-tensor, geodesics

Let $(M,g)$ be a 4 dimensional Lorentz spacetime. A smooth curve $\alpha:\ I\to M$ is called lightlike if $\alpha'(s)\in TM_{\alpha(s)}$ is lightlike for all $s\in I$, which means
$$g_{\alpha(s)}\big(\alpha'(s),\alpha'(s) \big)=0,\ \forall s\in I. $$
A geodesic in $M$ is a smooth curve $\alpha:\ I\to M$ such that $\alpha''=0$. A geodesic which is also a lightlike curve is called a lightlike geodesic.

I wonder if there is an example of a lightlike curve that is not a geodesic ? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76170/2451